# nullreferenceexception was unhandled NAudio MP3 streaming

Tags: c#, streaming, mp3, naudio

I am using Naudios Demo app to demostrait a litle bit. I found out that when i play some mp3 file, in the end om the sound/mp3 i get a

> error nullreferenceexception was unhandled
>   nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

in the file Mp3FrameDecompressor.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.Wave.Compression;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace NAudio.Wave
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MP3 Frame Decompressor using ACM
    /// </summary>
    public class AcmMp3FrameDecompressor : IDisposable, IMp3FrameDecompressor
    {
        private AcmStream conversionStream;
        private WaveFormat pcmFormat;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new ACM frame decompressor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sourceFormat">The MP3 source format</param>
        public AcmMp3FrameDecompressor(WaveFormat sourceFormat)
        {
            this.pcmFormat = AcmStream.SuggestPcmFormat(sourceFormat);
            conversionStream = new AcmStream(sourceFormat, pcmFormat);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Output format (PCM)
        /// </summary>
        public WaveFormat OutputFormat { get { return pcmFormat; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decompresses a frame
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="frame">The MP3 frame</param>
        /// <param name="dest">destination buffer</param>
        /// <param name="destOffset">Offset within destination buffer</param>
        /// <returns>Bytes written into destination buffer</returns>
        public int DecompressFrame(Mp3Frame frame, byte[] dest, int destOffset)
        {
            Array.Copy(frame.RawData, conversionStream.SourceBuffer, frame.FrameLength);
            int sourceBytesConverted = 0;
            int converted = conversionStream.Convert(frame.FrameLength, out sourceBytesConverted);
            if (sourceBytesConverted != frame.FrameLength)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Couldn't convert the whole MP3 frame (converted {0}/{1})",
                    sourceBytesConverted, frame.FrameLength));
            }
            Array.Copy(conversionStream.DestBuffer, 0, dest, destOffset, converted);
            return converted;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes of this MP3 frame decompressor
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this.conversionStream != null)
            {
                this.conversionStream.Dispose();
                this.conversionStream = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Form i use

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace NAudioDemo
{
    public partial class MP3StreamingPanel : Form
    {
        public MP3StreamingPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.volumeSlider1.VolumeChanged += new EventHandler(volumeSlider1_VolumeChanged);
            this.Disposed += this.MP3StreamingPanel_Disposing;
        }

        enum StreamingPlaybackState
        {
            Stopped,
            Playing,
            Buffering,
            Paused
        }

        void volumeSlider1_VolumeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.volumeProvider != null)
            {
                this.volumeProvider.Volume = this.volumeSlider1.Volume;
            }
        }

        private BufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider;
        private IWavePlayer waveOut;
        private volatile StreamingPlaybackState playbackState;
        private volatile bool fullyDownloaded;
        private HttpWebRequest webRequest;
        private VolumeWaveProvider16 volumeProvider;

        delegate void ShowErrorDelegate(string message);

        private void ShowError(string message)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new ShowErrorDelegate(ShowError), message);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(message);
            }
        }

        private void StreamMP3(object state)
        {
            this.fullyDownloaded = false;
            string url = (string)state;
            webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse resp = null;
            try
            {
                resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            }
            catch(WebException e)
            {
                if (e.Status != WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
                {
                    ShowError(e.Message);
                }
                return;
            }
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16384 * 4]; // needs to be big enough to hold a decompressed frame

            IMp3FrameDecompressor decompressor = null;
            try
            {
                using (var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var readFullyStream = new ReadFullyStream(responseStream);
                    do
                    {
                        if (bufferedWaveProvider != null && bufferedWaveProvider.BufferLength - bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedBytes < bufferedWaveProvider.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 4)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Buffer getting full, taking a break");
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Mp3Frame frame = null;
                            try
                            {
                                frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(readFullyStream);
                            }
                            catch (EndOfStreamException)
                            {
                                this.fullyDownloaded = true;
                                // reached the end of the MP3 file / stream
                                break;
                            }
                            catch (WebException)
                            {
                                // probably we have aborted download from the GUI thread
                                break;
                            }
                            if (decompressor == null)
                            {
                                // don't think these details matter too much - just help ACM select the right codec
                                // however, the buffered provider doesn't know what sample rate it is working at
                                // until we have a frame
                                WaveFormat waveFormat = new Mp3WaveFormat(frame.SampleRate, frame.ChannelMode == ChannelMode.Mono ? 1 : 2, frame.FrameLength, frame.BitRate);
                                decompressor = new AcmMp3FrameDecompressor(waveFormat);
                                this.bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(decompressor.OutputFormat);
                                this.bufferedWaveProvider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20); // allow us to get well ahead of ourselves
                                //this.bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedDuration = 250;
                            }
                            int decompressed = decompressor.DecompressFrame(frame, buffer, 0);
                            //Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Decompressed a frame {0}", decompressed));
                            bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, decompressed);
                        }

                    } while (playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Exiting");
                    // was doing this in a finally block, but for some reason
                    // we are hanging on response stream .Dispose so never get there
                    decompressor.Dispose();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (decompressor != null)
                {
                    decompressor.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        private void buttonPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped)
            {
                playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Buffering;
                this.bufferedWaveProvider = null;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(StreamMP3), textBoxStreamingUrl.Text);
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else if (playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Paused)
            {
                playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Buffering;
            }
        }

        private void StopPlayback()
        {
            if (playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped)
            {
                if (!fullyDownloaded)
                {
                    webRequest.Abort();
                }
                this.playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped;
                if (waveOut != null)
                { 
                    waveOut.Stop();
                    waveOut.Dispose();
                    waveOut = null;
                }
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                // n.b. streaming thread may not yet have exited
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                ShowBufferState(0);
            }
        }

        private void ShowBufferState(double totalSeconds)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped)
            {
                if (this.waveOut == null && this.bufferedWaveProvider != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Creating WaveOut Device");
                    this.waveOut = CreateWaveOut();
                    waveOut.PlaybackStopped += waveOut_PlaybackStopped;
                    this.volumeProvider = new VolumeWaveProvider16(bufferedWaveProvider);
                    this.volumeProvider.Volume = this.volumeSlider1.Volume;
                    waveOut.Init(volumeProvider);
                    progressBarBuffer.Maximum = (int)bufferedWaveProvider.BufferDuration.TotalMilliseconds;
                }
                else if (bufferedWaveProvider != null)
                {
                    var bufferedSeconds = bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedDuration.TotalSeconds;
                    ShowBufferState(bufferedSeconds);
                    // make it stutter less if we buffer up a decent amount before playing
                    if (bufferedSeconds < 0.5 && this.playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Playing && !this.fullyDownloaded)
                    {
                        this.playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Buffering;
                        waveOut.Pause();
                        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Paused to buffer, waveOut.PlaybackState={0}", waveOut.PlaybackState));
                    }
                    else if (bufferedSeconds > 1 && this.playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Buffering)
                    {
                        waveOut.Play();
                        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Started playing, waveOut.PlaybackState={0}", waveOut.PlaybackState));
                        this.playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Playing;
                    }
                    else if (this.fullyDownloaded && bufferedSeconds == 0)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Reached end of stream");
                        StopPlayback();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private IWavePlayer CreateWaveOut()
        {
            return new WaveOut();
            //return new DirectSoundOut();
        }

        private void MP3StreamingPanel_Disposing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StopPlayback();
        }

        private void buttonPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Playing || playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Buffering)
            {
                waveOut.Pause();
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("User requested Pause, waveOut.PlaybackState={0}", waveOut.PlaybackState));
                playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Paused;
            }
        }

        private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StopPlayback();
        }

        private void waveOut_PlaybackStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Playback Stopped");
            if (e.Exception != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Playback Error {0}", e.Exception.Message));
            }
        }
    }

    [Export(typeof(INAudioDemoPlugin))]
    public class MP3StreamingPanelPlugin : INAudioDemoPlugin
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return "MP3 Streaming"; }
        }

        public Control CreatePanel()
        {
            return new MP3StreamingPanel();
        }
    }
}
```

i get the error on this line

```
Array.Copy(frame.RawData, conversionStream.SourceBuffer, frame.FrameLength);
```

Comment: Could you simply tell us the line where you get the exception?

Comment: This line 

Array.Copy(frame.RawData, conversionStream.SourceBuffer, frame.FrameLength);